# How samples are aligned in the audio file?

Tags: audio, core-audio

I'm trying to better understand how samples are aligned in the audio file.

Let's say we have a `2s` audio file with `sampling rate = 3`.
I think there are three possible ways to align those samples. Looking at the picture below, can you tell me which one is correct?

Also, is this a standard for all audio files or does different formats have different rules?

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sampling rate in audio typically tells you how many samples are in one second, a unit called Hertz. Strictly speaking, the correct answer would be (1), as you have 3 samples within one second. Assuming there's no latency, PCM and other formats dictate that audio starts at `0`. Next "cycle" (next second) also starts at zero, same principle like with a clock.

To get total length of the audio (following question in the comment), you should simply take `number of samples / rate`. Example from a 30s WAV using [soxi](https://linux.die.net/man/1/soxi), one of canonical tools used in the community for sound manipulation:

```
Input File     : 'book_00396_chp_0024_reader_11416_5_door_Freesound_validated_380721_0-door_Freesound_validated_381380_0-9IfN8dUgGaQ_snr10_fileid_1138.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 16000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:00:30.00 = 480000 samples ~ 2250 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 960k
Bit Rate       : 256k
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

`480000 samples / (16000 samples / seconds) = 30 seconds` exactly. Citing manual, duration is "Equivalent to number of samples divided by the sample-rate."

Comment: Thanks Lukasz. It does make sense but if #1 is correct then how can I measure duration of the audio? Is it `number_of_samples / rate`? If so, this would mean that the last sample is not at the exact end of the audio. Is this correct?

So what would be the formula to calculate sample's time? Is this correct: `time = sample_idx / (rate + 1)` (where samples are indexed from 0).

Comment: @msmialko The formula `number_of_samples / rate` is correct, with units `samples / (samples / seconds) = seconds`, assuming rate is in `Hz`. Last sample is the end of the audio by definition - why wouldn't it be?

Comment: If the formula for duration is as you say, isn’t the example #3 the correct alignment of the samples? In the example #1, the last sample is actually before 2s mark. There are 6 samples in total, recorded with 3Hz frequency. Shouldn’t that mean that the last sample is exactly at 2s?

Comment: The `2s` mark is the start of a new cycle, same as `0s` is the beginning. If there was a sample at `2s` in example #1, it'd mean the who sample is more than 2 seconds long. Formally length of all three is identical. Remember that in this reasoning you try to apply a continous measurement framework (time in seconds) to discrete measurements, which might cause problems with interpretation (due to disontinuity).

Comment: I guess it's accurate to think about "duration" of each sample which could be defined as `1 / frequency`. In our example it's `1/3 sec` and it's the time between samples. And so the total audio duration could be defined as `last_sample_timestamp + sample_duration`. My intuition is that it's correct because the wave is interpolated to `0` after last sample and it takes time as well.